# How to separate Interface and common implementation

Tags: matlab, oop, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
IMyObject % common interface defining methods and properties (abstract properties are supported by MATLAB)
A < IMyObject
B < IMyObject
...
```

`IMyObject` should act as interface and if possible not contain code.

There are many classes (A,B,...) derived from IMyObject and 90% of those share code for certain methods.

The straight forward way is to use an abstract class rather than an interface and just define all this code in IMyObject (possible renaming it to MyObjectRoot, MyObjectMaster, AbstractMyObject or similar). The 10% which do not share code of the mentioned methods would overwrite them.

However, I would like to have an explicit interface class (to separate the interface from code).

I use a "programming language" that supports multiple inheritance (MATLAB).

Now I may use the approach to create a class `MyObject_GenericCode` and the 90% classes would not only inherit from `IMyObject` but also from the `MyObject_Generic` class.

Since this generic class need access to the data (the abstract properties from `IMyObject`), they would also need to be derived from it.

Example:

```
MyObject_GenericCode < IMyObject
...
% the 90% classes having some kind of common code:
A < IMyObject & MyObject_GenericCode
B < IMyObject & MyObject_GenericCode
....
% 10% just use the interface and implement everything ob their own
Z < IMyObject
```

The problem is the diamond problem - but it's more theoretic in this case because I think there would not be such cases.

Apart from that - is there anything discouraging about that?

Finally, I found out that in MATLAB I can avoid this because the generic code classes do not need to be inherited from IMyObject but can still access the properties from the supplied object.

Example:

```
classdef IMyObject
    properties (Abstract)
        Fc;
    end
    methods (Abstract)
        test(this);
    end
end

classdef MyObject_GenericCode
    methods
        function test(this)
            fprintf(1, 'Value of Fc: %d\n', this.Fc);
        end
    end
end

classdef A < IMyObject & MyObject_GenericCode
    properties
        Fc;
    end

    methods
        function this = A()
            this.Fc = 999;
        end
    end
end

myObj = A();
myObj.test();
```

which returns

```
Value of Fc: 999
```

without error. Although this works it sounds a bit "fishy" to me.

Which way is the appropriate option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use multiple inheritance in your case. Matlab's OOP does not have explicit interface classes, but if a class only consists of abstract methods and properties, in effect it acts like an interface. Generic class may implement a part of that interface, leaving some methods/properties abstract, to be implemented by a subclass.

So your hierarchy could look like this:

```
classdef IMyObject
    properties (Abstract)
        Fc;
    end
    methods (Abstract)
        test(this);
    end
end

classdef MyObject_GenericCode < IMyObject
    properties (Abstract)
        Fc;
    end

    methods
        function test(this)
            fprintf(1, 'Value of Fc: %d\n', this.Fc);
        end
    end
end

classdef A < MyObject_GenericCode
    properties
        Fc;
    end

    methods
        function this = A()
            this.Fc = 999;
        end
    end
end
```